# how to check if timer is expired in python?

Tags: python, time, timer

I am having some questions related to python timer. Hope someone can give some suggestions on that. :)

I would like when the timer is expired after 20sec, then it printout a string and exit(2), I look into some example hence, I have written the first example below, the problem for that is after timeout, event I have written sys.exit(2) in the function, it will not exit it with 2, but with exit code 0 instead.

```
import sys
import threading

def application_timeout():
    print("The application is timeout\n")
    sys.exit(2)

timer = threading.Timer(20.0, application_timeout)
timer.start()
```

Below is my second example, I am managed to make the code exit 2, but the code doesn't look as nice. Just wondering can someone give me a suggestion on that?

import sys
import threading

```
def application_timeout():
    print("The application is timeout\n")

timer = threading.Timer(20.0, application_timeout)
timer.start()
while(timer.is_alive() == True):
    timerstillalive = False

if(timerstillalive == False):
    print("Timer is expired")
    sys.exit(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because Thread's run method **ignores** SystemExit. From threading [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

> If the run() method raises an exception, threading.excepthook() is called to handle it. **By default, threading.excepthook() ignores silently SystemExit**.

You want to exit 2 when the `application_timeout` function returns. In that case, you can use `Event`,

```
event = threading.Event()

def application_timeout():
    print("The application is timeout\n")
    event.set()

timer = threading.Timer(20.0, application_timeout)
timer.start()

event.wait()
sys.exit(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

---

easy thing would be:

```
while timer.is_alive():
     pass

print("Timer is expired")
sys.exit(2)
```

That is just nicer looking, but does the same thing

---

funnier method:

```
pip install waiting
```

a nice library to wait until condition is true

```
wait(lambda: (False if timer.is_alive() else True), timeout_seconds=1, waiting_for="Timer to be expired")
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one is good enough, but you can simplify it by checking `timer.is_alive()` directly.

```
def application_timeout():
    print("The application is timeout\n")

timer = threading.Timer(20.0, application_timeout)
timer.start()
while(timer.is_alive() == True):
   pass
print("Timer is expired")
sys.exit(2)
```